# Why does my string color in python-docx not change

Tags: python, python-docx

My problem is that my string color does not change, The strings name is "TitluCentru". I need to set the color to light blue.

```
import docx
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

doc = docx.Document()

TitluCentru = doc.add_paragraph('NOTIFICARE') 
TitluCentru_format = TitluCentru.paragraph_format
TitluCentru_format.alignment
TitluCentru_format.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
TitluCentru_format.alignment

TitluStanga.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0x22, 0x8b, 0x22)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with docx, but I notice you do all the work to TitluCentru but change the font in TitluStanga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out for you, but it is not awesome. This has to be the most convoluted package I have ever had to work with. I was determined to at least make it work, and I did!

I'm sorry, I really can't explain this to you with any confidence. All I can tell you is it works. I checked it in LibraOffice and 'NOTIFICARE' was green, just like I told it to be. Hopefully you can take this info and do something with it. I don't want to mess with this package, ever again. I can give you this tidbit, though. If you moved your text directly into `add_paragraph` but left everything else exactly how I have it, 'NOTIFICARE' will NOT change color. The color get's applied to whatever is in the `run`. So, I'm assuming if you have a lot of color changing to do, your program is going to be a whole lot of the hot mess, below.

I hope somebody else that knows what they are doing answers your question. I want to compare my answer with the "real one". I didn't find this info. I trudged through the docs storing tidbits and tried so many combinations that I eventually got lucky. I'm having a hard time believing it's this convoluted to assign a color to text. Honestly if I had to use this, I would just make the entire doc in html and throw it in a converter.

```
import docx
from docx.shared import RGBColor

doc = docx.Document()

r = doc.add_paragraph().add_run('NOTIFICARE')

r.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0x00, 0xFF, 0x00)

doc.save('test.docx')
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and for trying so hard to making it work

Comment: @IoshuaBerdei - You're welcome but this site doesn't work on thanks it works by you selecting answers with the big check mark to the left of answers. I just noticed that you've never selected ANY of the answers you were given. That's not right! You need to go select the answers that helped you.! That's 100% why people answer questions. That's why nobody else answered this question. You're making a name for yourself as someone to ignore. Go check the answers that solved your questions! 1 per question.

Comment: I understand what are you saying but i cant up vote your question because I don t have enough reputation.

Comment: I see, thanks man I am going to check all the marks I didnt  check .